# Facebook redirect issue with angular app in hashbang mode

Tags: angularjs, facebook, redirect, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I have an issue with facebook oauth redirection. My angular app uses hashbang mode (#!) and its url is **www.abc.org/#!/**
I have tried to put this url in the **"valid oauth redirect uri"** field in my app's dashboard but facebook doesn't accept hashbang urls. Putting www.abc.org in the dashboard is leading facebook to redirect to **www.abc.org/?#access_token="...."** instead of **www.abc.org/#!/?#access_token=".."**
Can someone suggest a way to fix this issue ?

PS: This app has no backend and hence using html5 mode will not be possible as i can't perform a server sided rewrite

Comment: What did you specify as redirect_uri value in your actual login dialog call? And why can't you take the token from `www.abc.org/?#access_token=`? That is still the same URL _path_ as `www.abc.org/#!/`, so there would be no need for any server-side rewriting regarding _this_ at all. You app _has_ already been loaded from that path.